# java 8 summing up a list of integer

Tags: java

**code**

```
public static int simpleArraySum(List<Integer> ar) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + ar[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

**where i believe the issue is**

how would I iterate through `List<Integer>` type is different a `int[] ar`

**Error**

```
Solution.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
                              ^ 
  
symbol:   variable length
  location: variable ar of type List<Integer>

Solution.java:29: error: array required, but List<Integer> found
            sum = sum + ar[i];
                      ^ 

2 errors
```

**what I tried:**

After changing `ar.length` to `ar.size()` I still have error

```
Solution.java:26: error: array required, but List<Integer> found
        sum = sum + ar[i];
                      ^
1 error
```

Comment: Try reading the java docs for `List` or `ArrayList`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to use `get` to retrieve a value from a `list` (which is not an array)

- change `length` to `size`
- use `get` to fetch the value at index `i`

```
public static int simpleListSum(List<Integer> ar) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++) {
        sum = sum + ar.get(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

But you can also do it using the enhanced for loop with no index. This also works for arrays.

```
public static int simpleListSum(List<Integer> ar) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int val : ar) {
       sum += val;
    }
    return sum;
}
```